# Align an image and text vertically in the middle?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center the text and an image in two columns. But, I tried everything but I could not manage to bring then in the vertical middle position of a .row .

```
      <div className="hidden-md">
        <div className="row navbar">
          <div className="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <image src="../resources/back_button.png" />
          </div>
          <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <span className="custom-input">Filters</span>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Can anyone help me with the css to align the text and the image in the middle I want to achieve the results shown in the image.

[image: This is the result]

Comment: so you want to align text vertically middle beside image?

Comment: @lakshmankambam I have added an image it will be more visible for you to understand.

Comment: check out the fiddle and let me know https://jsfiddle.net/klakshman318/fsvwp61h/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/klakshman318/fsvwp61h/3/)

```css
.vertical-align{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img{
  border:3px solid #2d2d2d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div className="hidden-md">
        <div className="row navbar">
          <div className="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <img src="http://www.free2go.com.au/-/media/allsites/competitions/content-image/free2go-beatsstudioheadphones-480x360.ashx?la=en" />
            <span className="custom-input vertical-align">Filters</span>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: In your case it is working but not in my case. The problem here is when I give height and width to image then it sticks to top. I tried giving vertical-align: middle; but the image does not move. Same with the text. I need to specify the padding to bring it in the center.

Comment: make jsfiddle and send me the link in chat.. i will take a look at it.

Comment: check with these two fiddles.. http://jsfiddle.net/klakshman318/2zaty6k1/1/

Comment: Thanks @LakshmanKambam the second last jsfiddle worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**You can make use of the Flexbox in this kind of situations, which is the best for use**

```
<div className="hidden-md">
    <div className="row navbar">
      <div className="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <image src="../resources/back_button.png" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <span className="custom-input">Filters</span>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: can you share a working jsfiddle, coz I tried above it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

( using Bootstrap 5 ) I have a button with an Image + text inside it.

Issue was in my case, I used a `float-end` on the image - which caused the text to behave like the image doesn't expand the button's height and therefore the text *was* vertical aligned but not to the image but rather to the button.

Removing the `float-end` made all child-elements vertical aligned.